# Javascript How can I get the href from no id anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="href">inner</a>
```

Function below doesn't work because there's no id:

```
document.getElementById("???").href
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: is there any other distinguishing feature about this particular `<a>` element on your page?

Comment: Can you show the HTML surrounding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to find the `a` elements:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

This will store all `a` elements into an array. If you know exactly which element you want, extract it from the array based on its order in the page and grab the `href`:

```
var href = anchor[1].href;
```

Example [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTWjr/) (watch for the `alert`)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `document.querySelector('a[href="href"]')` and get the element by attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getElemntsByTagName. It's probably better just to add in an id attribute though...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested `getElementsByTagName` is the right way to go if the element doesn't have an id or a class. But thats going to give you a `NodeList` of all the anchor links you have on your DOM.

So, if you can add an id or class to the anchor link, that's your best option. If that's not an option, see if you can wrap your anchor link with a div with a unique id/class (lets say id is `unique-wrapper`) & use this.

```
document.getElementById('unique-wrapper').getElementsByTagName('a')
```

See [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/t4zwx/2/)